# Привидение классов php

Tags: php, ооп

```
class A {

  public function foo() {
  }
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Как после создания класса B представить его классом A

```
$b = new B();
```

Нужно "превратить", "откатить", "представить" классом A.
Потом выполнить метод foo() 
ВАЖНО: Вызывать $b->foo() не нужно пока он не превратился в A.

```
parent::foo()
```

Не помогает

Answer (score 2):

1. Объект какого-то класса не может "превратиться" в объект другого класса. Тип объекта задается **при его создании**.
2. Объект класса (ссылка на объект) может быть помещен в переменную **любого** типа ниже по иерархии наследования. Например, объект типа В может быть помещен в переменную типа А.
3. Набор методов, которые можно будет вызывать для объекта определяется **типом переменной**, в которую помещен объект, а не самим объектом. Набор методов определяется интерфейсами, которые имплементирует класс, который задан в типе переменной.
4. Если объект помещен в нетипизированную переменную (object), то можно вызывать любой публичный метод объекта. Это называется поздним связыванием. Т.е. на этапе компиляции система вообще не знает о том, какой метод будет тут выполняться и есть ли реализация этого метода в объекте, помещенном в данную переменную. Во время выполнения будет сделан поиск в наборе методов, имплементируемых **объектом**, помещенным в переменную и, если нужный метод будет найден, то он будет выполнен. Если не найден - будет ошибка времени выполнения.
5. Содержимое метода, которое будет выполнено при вызове, определяется **типом объекта**, который помещен в переменную. А **не** типом переменной, в которую помещен объект.

Из сказанного выше следует, что вызвать **реализацию** метода foo определенную в классе А можно в случаях:

1. Если метод foo **не** перекрыт в наследнике, то его можно вызвать и для переменной типа В и для переменной типа А. Разницы нет. Все равно будет выполнена реализация А.
2. Если метод foo **перекрыт** в наследнике, то реализацию метода, сделанную в классе А напрямую вызывать **не** получится. Независимо от того, какой тип переменной задан А или В, будет выполняться реализация созданного объекта - если создан объект типа В, то будет выполняться реализация класса В.
3. Если все же необходимо выполнять именно реализацию, определенную в классе А для объекта класса В, то можно пойти тремя путями:

Первый вариант - оставить метод foo в классе В не перекрытым, тогда будет выполняться реализация А, а нужную функциональность для класса В реализовать в методе fooB, в котором уже вызывать parent::foo().

Второй вариант - определить в классе В новый метод fooA в котором вызывать parent::foo()

Последний, **самый правильный вариант** - выделить общую функциональность для всех классов в отдельный метод fooBase в классе А. И вызывать по необходимости этот метод в нужном меcте в классах наследниках или определить его интерфейсным и вызывать где нужно в программе.

PS. Я не очень хорошо знаю ООП именно в PHP. Возможно, в PHP есть еще другие варианты вызова метода предка типа extension методов. Если такое есть, то пусть дополнят мой ответ гуру от PHP.